# windows The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'temp.csv'

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, dataframe

I am trying to insert values of a dataframe to postgres database. for that i am treating a temporary csv file and load the csv file, load the csv in buffer and using copy_from() i am inserting it into the database.
But Here I am getting an error `[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'temp.csv'`

No other application is open except pycharm. Can some please help!

```
def copy_from_datafile(conn, df_s, table):
"""
save the given dataframe on disk as a csv file,
load the csv file in buffer and use copy_from() to copy it to the pgsql database table
"""

if table == "symbols_option":
    command= '''CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _symbol (
        instrument_token INTEGER NOT NULL, exchange_token INTEGER, tradingsymbol TEXT NOT NULL, name TEXT,
        expiry TIMESTAMP, strike DOUBLE PRECISION, lot_size INTEGER,instrument_type TEXT, segment TEXT NOT NULL, exchange TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (instrument_token,
        tradingsymbol));'''
    query_main = '''INSERT INTO {table}(instrument_token, exchange_token, tradingsymbol, name, expiry, strike, lot_size,instrument_type, segment, exchange )
                SELECT * FROM _symbol
                ON CONFLICT (instrument_token, tradingsymbol)
                DO NOTHING
            '''.format(table=table)
if table == "symbols_future":
    command= '''CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _symbol (
        instrument_token INTEGER NOT NULL,exchange_token INTEGER, tradingsymbol TEXT NOT NULL,name TEXT,
        expiry TIMESTAMP,lot_size INTEGER,instrument_type TEXT, segment TEXT NOT NULL, exchange TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (instrument_token,
        tradingsymbol));'''
    query_main = '''INSERT INTO {table}(instrument_token, exchange_token, tradingsymbol,name, expiry,lot_size,instrument_type, segment, exchange )
                        SELECT * FROM _symbol
                        ON CONFLICT (instrument_token, tradingsymbol)
                        DO NOTHING
                    '''.format(table=table)


tmp_df = 'temp.csv'
df_s.to_csv(tmp_df, header=False, index=False)
f = open(tmp_df, 'r')
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    if table == "symbols_option":
    # cursor.execute(command)
        cursor.execute(command)
        cursor.copy_from(f, '_symbol', sep=",", columns=["instrument_token", "exchange_token", "tradingsymbol", "name", "expiry", "strike", "lot_size","instrument_type", "segment", "exchange" ])
        cursor.execute(query_main)
        print("Data inserted using copy_from_datafile() successfully....")
    else:
        cursor.execute(command)
        cursor.copy_from(f, '_symbol', sep=",", columns=[
        "instrument_token", "exchange_token", "tradingsymbol", "name", "expiry", "lot_size",
        "instrument_type", "segment", "exchange"])
        cursor.execute(query_main)
        print("Data inserted using copy_from_datafile() successfully....")
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as err:
    os.remove(tmp_df)
    print(err)
    cursor.close()
else:
    os.remove(tmp_df)
```

Comment: You can view in resource monitor in windows what process it is being used by. Run ResMon.exe and click on disk tab.

Comment: looks like some issue specific to windows. same code is working fine in mac os.